# Make Accept Terms and conditions fields required in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I have a checkbox in vue.js

```
<input  v-model="form.accept" name="Accept" type="checkbox" value="false">
```

i have model defined

```
 data() {
        return {
            form: new Form({
                accept: false,
```

now i want to make this field required

```
 'accept' =>'required|true',
```

but this is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change value="true"

```
<input  v-model="form.accept" name="Accept" type="checkbox" value="true">
```

And change rules to

```
'accept' => 'accepted',
```